# How to add/replace the SourceFile attribute in a .class file

Tags: java, .class-file

I want to add/replace the `SourceFile` attribute in a compiled Java `.class` file. I have not noticed any obscure command-line options to the Java compiler to override the default value of `SourceFile`. Neither have I seen anything in the Java reflection API that would help me. Skim reading chapter 4 of the JVM specification indicates I could spend a few weeks writing a `.class` file parser/modifier to do the work. Before I invest the effort to write such a parser/modifier, I want to check if I am missing something. Is there anything in the standard JDK to help with adding/replacing the `SourceFile` attribute?

For anyone wondering why I would want to mess with the `SourceFile` attribute... I have a command-line tool that preprocesses a "Java enhanced with some syntactic sugar" file into Java syntax. The file-name extension for this type of file is `.bi`. Thus, the preprocessor converts `Foo.bi` into `Foo.java`. In addition, there is line-number correspondence between `Foo.bi` and `Foo.java`, so if a runtime error occurs on, say, line 42 of `Foo.java`, then the bug should really be fixed on line 42 of `Foo.bi` (and then run the preprocessor and compile the updated `Foo.java` file). To facilitate this, I would like the stack trace of the error to indicate `Foo.bi` rather than `Foo.java`, and my experiments suggest this can be achieved by ensuring the `Foo.class` file has a `SourceFile` attribute with a value of `Foo.bi`.

Comment: So the line numbers don’t need an adaptation?

Comment: @Holger Correct: line *N* of `Foo.java` corresponds to line *N* of `Foo.bi`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such feature in the standard JDK API, but before trying to implement a bytecode processor yourself, consider using a 3rd party library like [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/). With that library, the task could be implemented like:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path in = Paths.get(URI.create("jrt:/java.base/java/lang/Object.class"));
    Path out = Files.createTempFile("Object", ".class");

    changeSourceAttr(in, out, "Object.bi");

    runJavaP(out);

    Files.delete(out);
}

private static void changeSourceAttr(Path in, Path out, String newValue)
    throws IOException {

    ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(Files.readAllBytes(in));
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(cr, 0);
    cr.accept(new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, cw) {
        boolean sourceSeen;
        @Override
        public void visitSource(String source, String debug) {
            sourceSeen = true;
            super.visitSource(newValue, debug);
        }

        @Override
        public void visitEnd() {
            if(!sourceSeen) {
                super.visitSource(newValue, null);
            }
            super.visitEnd();
        }
    }, 0);
    byte[] code = cw.toByteArray();
    Files.write(out, code);
}

private static void runJavaP(Path out) {
    ToolProvider.findFirst("javap")
        .ifPresent(tp -> tp.run(System.out, System.err, out.toString()));
}
```

```
Compiled from "Object.bi"
public class java.lang.Object {
  public java.lang.Object();
  public final native java.lang.Class<?> getClass();
  public native int hashCode();
  public boolean equals(java.lang.Object);
  protected native java.lang.Object clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException;
  public java.lang.String toString();
  public final native void notify();
  public final native void notifyAll();
  public final void wait() throws java.lang.InterruptedException;
  public final native void wait(long) throws java.lang.InterruptedException;
  public final void wait(long, int) throws java.lang.InterruptedException;
  protected void finalize() throws java.lang.Throwable;
}
```

The relevant part is the `changeSourceAttr` method. It will change the source file attribute if present or add a new one otherwise.

The example changes the attribute for the `java.lang.Object` class using a temporary file and runs `javap` to show the result. The example code requires JDK9+, the actual transformation method should work on previous versions too. When the source file does not originate from the JDK library, source and target may be the same file.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, complete with sample code. That will save me weeks of effort by not having to re-invent the wheel.